# NOT NULL constraint failed: new__store_product.category_id

Tags: python, django, django-models

after i add category field to my model i am facing this error. where is the problem?

from django.db import models

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    price = models.IntegerField()
    des = models.TextField()
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE,default=1)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='products/pics')


    def __str__(self):
        return self.name`enter code here`
```

Comment: What is the view that raises the error, share the code of the view.

Comment: after deleting some migrations file it works fine...thank you